# Error creating tables from within stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ddl

I have created following stored procedure. But it gives a syntax error. I am not able to point out the problem.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE createtables()
BEGIN
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;
CREATE TABLE employee(eid int PRIMARY KEY, ename varchar(45));
CREATE TABLE account(accid int PRIMARY KEY, amount float);
CREATE TABLE department(dip int PRIMARY KEY, depname varchar(45), eid int, FOREIGN KEY(dip) REFERENCES employee(eid));
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot use `USE` in stored procedures. So instead try:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE createtables()
BEGIN
CREATE DATABASE test;
CREATE TABLE test.employee(eid int PRIMARY KEY, ename varchar(45));
CREATE TABLE test.account(accid int PRIMARY KEY, amount float);
CREATE TABLE test.department(dip int PRIMARY KEY, depname varchar(45), eid int, FOREIGN KEY(dip) REFERENCES test.employee(eid));
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: needs to say `REFERENCES test.employee(eid)` as well.  Edited.